# Which Data Structure/Algorithm concept does Facebook use for Friend Suggestions?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Facebook suggests people we might know.

It shows us people we have looked up for.
And people who look up our profile.

I am curious to know which Algorithm does Facebook use for achieving this. Also the Data Structure that might help for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather answer on how this could be achieved.

Consider a Graph where Nodes are people and you have different kinds of vertices:

- v1: The people N is friends with (undirected)
- v2: The people whose wall were visited by N (directed, weighted by visit number)
- v3: The people whose shared articles were seen by N (directed, weighted by article number)
- v4: The people who commented/liked/shared on N's any activity (directed, weighted by a formula based on the number of actions of different kinds)
- v5: The people mentioned in a post/comment of N (directed)

Indirect paths should be taken into account (friend of a friend), N is a Node. Based on the attributes of the graph the likelyness of the person is known can be computed by a formula, which can be defined in infinitely many ways. Also, one person might know another one, who forgot about the first one. Also, v(i) list is far from complete, it is meant only as an illustration.

Comment: it's also called "Missing link prediction" and for some creative solutions go and checkout https://www.kaggle.com/c/FacebookRecruiting